# Calculate average using SSE with STL vectors

Tags: c++, math, sse

I'm trying to learn about vectorisation, and rather than reinvet the wheel I'm using [Agner Fog's vector library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass)

Here's my original C++/STL code

```
#include <vector>
#include <vectorclass.h>   
template<typename T>
double mean_v1(T begin,T end) {
        float mean = 0;
        std::for_each(begin,end,[&mean](const double& d) { mean+=d; });

    return mean / std::distance(begin,end);
}

double mean_v2(T begin,T end) {
    float mean = 0;
    const int distance = std::distance(begin,end); // This is expensive
    const int loop = ( distance >> 2)+1; // divide by 4
    const int partial = distance & 2; // remainder 4
    Vec4d vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < loop;++i) {
        if(i == (loop-1)) {
            vec.load_partial(partial,&*begin);
            mean = horizontal_add(vec);
        }
        else  {
            vec.load(&*begin);
            mean = horizontal_add(vec);
            begin+=4; // This is expensive
        }
    }
    return mean / distance;
}

int main(int argc,char**argv) {
    using namespace boost::assign;
    std::vector<float> numbers;
    // Note 13 numbers, which won't fit into a sse register perfectly
    numbers+=39.57,39.57,39.604,39.58,39.61,31.669,31.669,31.669,31.65,32.09,33.54,32.46,33.45;

    const float mean1 = mean_v1(numbers.begin(),numbers.end());
    const float mean2 = mean_v2(numbers.begin(),numbers.end());


    return 0;
}
```

Both v1 and v2 work correctly and they both take about the same time. However profiling it shows the the std::distance() and moving the iterator along takes almost 45% of the total time. The vector adds is just 0.8% which is significantly faster than v1.

Searching the web, all the examples seem to deal with perfect number of values that fit precisely into the SSE registers. How do people deal with odd numbers of values eg for this example where setting up the loop is taking a lot longer than the calculation.

I'm thinking there must be best practices or ideas on how to deal with this scenario.

Assume I can't change the interface of mean() to take float[], but must use iterators

Comment: Just as advice: Maybe Thrust library will be interesting to you, https://code.google.com/p/thrust/

Comment: That does indeed look interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing float & double unnecessarily, especially as you don't let your accumulator be double your precision is totally destroyed and won't be close to satisfactory for larger series.

As the arithmetic is super light weight what's destroying your performance here is most likely  memory access, read up on memory cache lines and how they work. Basically what you need to do here is probe ahead, some processors have explicit instructions for pulling stuff into your cache, otherwise you can perform a load at a memory location ahead of time. Create another level of nesting in your loop and at regular intervals prime the cache with data you know you will get to in a few iterations.

What people do to maximize performance is that they spend a lot of time actually designing their data layout. You shouldn't need to do an intermediate transformation on your data. So what people do is they allocate aligned memory ( most SIMD instruction sets either requires or imposes grave penalties for reading / writing to unaligned memory ), and then they try to aggregate data in such a way that it fits the instruction set. In fact it's often a win to pad your data up to whatever register size the instruction set supports. So if lets say you're going to process 3 dimensional vectors, padding with an extra element which is unused will almost always be a big win.

Comment: They are very useful guidelines; but it does mean that I have to restructure the way an algorithm is called to fit the optimisation. In this case, it's part of a larger algorithmic trading code.

Comment: @Ylisar, processing a 3D vector with one SSE or AVX register by padding extra elements is definitely NOT what you want to do.  Too many people make this mistake with SIMD.  The correct way to use SIMD is similar to scalar code.  The difference is that e.g. with a 3D vector instead of using three x, y, z scalar registers you use three SIMD registers (vx =xxxx, vy=yyyy, vz=zzzz) and operate on a number of vectors equal to the SIMD width at once.  This gets you 100% efficiency and avoids having to use horizontal instructions.

Comment: @redrum - Probably because it's way more flexible to organize data as AoS than SoA. Besides, SoA have way worse cache behavior than AoS. To be honest I've only ever seen SoA been used for very limited data sets like particles.

Comment: @Yilsar, the correct usagege is AoSoA or a hybrid SoA.  Your claim that a SoA has "way worse" cache behavior than a AoS is false.  That's one of the main reason to use a SoA (or rather a AoSoA) - because it's more cache friendly.  AoSoA are used in many applications e.g. in matrix multiplication and ray tracing.